# R functions similar to "outer" but return a list

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, plyr

I have two vectors, a and b, and these two vectors are not of the same length. I wish to evaluate a function f over all possible combinations of the entries in a and b. A possible solution is:
    `outer(a,b,f)`.

However, outer function only returns 2-d array, and the function f returns a list. I am wondering whether there are functions similar to outer that can return a list.

I checked the package plyr/dplyr and didn't find a similar function. I know the problem could be solved by for-loops, nested lapply, or "outer" the arguments a and b into an array at first and then using apply. I am wondering whether there are elegant ways to solve this problem.

Comment: `combn` has an argument to apply a function to the combinations.  But this is too broad as it stands.  We need some specifics.

Comment: `outer` should be able to return a matric with entries that are lists. My guess is that your `f` function is not vectorized.  `?Vectorize`

Comment: Agree with close voter who said need code. We've waited long enough for a response to that request.  Look at the SO help page: [MCVE]

Comment: Here's coding proof that the claim about outer not handling lists is just false: `x = 1:3;
y = 6:7; f <- function(a,b) { lapply(a, function(a) list(a,b) )}; outer(x,y,f)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lapply`

```
x = 1:3
y = 6:7
```

**1. using `outer`**

```
outer(x, y, "+")
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    7    8
#[2,]    8    9
#[3,]    9   10
```

**2. using `lapply`**

```
lapply(x, function(a) a+y)
#[[1]]
#[1] 7 8

#[[2]]
#[1] 8 9

#[[3]]
#[1]  9 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there any other using a single function to accomplish this without using outer at first?

Comment: Might well need `lapply(a, function(a){ lapply(b, function(b){f(a,b)}) })`. My guess is that his `f` has not been vectorized, and if so, your example with "+" is misleading.